# What secret is used to sign JWT tokens in AWS Cognito if client secret is not generated

Tags: amazon-cognito

When I create a new `app client` in AWS Cognito, I have an option not to generate `client secret` (I need to disable this because as far as I understand nodejs apps do not support this secret), so I am wondering what key is then used to sign the JWT tokens that are issued by Cognito

Answer (score 2):

The client secret is not used to sign JWT tokens. The private key is used to sign a token and public key to verify it. You can view public keys for your User Pool by next URL:

```
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json
```

More information about this can be found in AWS documentation - [Verifying a JSON Web Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Having a client secret depends from whether you are going to use the implicit or the explicit(or authorization_code) grant for authorization. Nodejs applications support both. Below I have an example of a request with authorization_code grant, where you need the secret when you will perform your request to Cognito's token endpoint (passed as headers in Authorization). 
`let enc = WNEMONITOR_APP_CLIENT_ID + ":" +WNEMONITOR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
request.post({
      url: 'https://YourCognitoUserPoolDomain.auth.yourregion..amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(enc),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: theurlofyourapplication,
        scope: 'email openid profile',
        client_id: WNEMONITOR_APP_CLIENT_ID
      }`

The response will be your id_token and the refresh_token (if you have configured it to your UserPool earlier, in the configuration of App Client, check box "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH")

In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html you can see the requests in each case.

In https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/ you can see the difference between the two grants (implicit - without secret, and authorization_code), do choose the best for your case. But it has nothing to do with the language that your application is written in.

In case you are convinced you don't need the authorization_code grant, you can configure not to have a secret like this:
In your User Pool in the AWS console go to App Clients (on your left), and on the client that you will create unclick the box "Generate client secret". I am not sure if you can edit an App client that you have already created. But I am sure that you can create a new one, and then use the client id of the new one to retrieve your token.